# I need an algorithm for scoring based on 1 variables ranking and 1 constant ranking

Tags: algorithm, variables

I have a program that is weighing a variable and a constant to classify the overall importance of a problem based on the degree of the problem and the importance of the category relative to the other categories.

1. The variable is the score 1-10 of the "problem" of the category 1 being the biggest problem, 10 being no problem at all.
2. The constant is the relative importance of the category, in my case 1-32, 1 being the most important.

So I have 32 categories that have a score of interpreted score of 1-10 based on how bad a problem is in that category.  I need to measure that against a relative importance of the category 1-32 and come up with a new order 1-32 factoring in the score of 1-10.

For example, if 1 is the category (1 being the most important) and it scores an 8 how does it relate to 19 scoring a 9?

Hopefully this explains what I am trying to do.

Comment: This site is for programming questions: it is not DesignMyAlgorithmForFree.com

Comment: In addition to what Mitch said, this sounds like a homework assignment (if it weren't, you'd have an idea of how to do it yourself). We don't do homework here, other than to look at what you've tried that doesn't work and giving suggestions about how to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic economics problem. You need to find a common measure of value and relate it to both the work needed to solve the problem and to the problem's importance. (The fact that one is "constant" and the other "variable" isn't really an issue.)